# Как стримить на Youtube с IP камеры видео со звуком?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, камера, потоки-данных, streaming

Подскажите программу или связку программ с помощью которых можно организовать трансляцию с IP камеры на Youtube.

Камера: `TP-Link TL-SC3130G`.

URL потока камеры: `rtsp://192.168.0.100:554/video.mp4`

Пробую через ffmpeg под Windows вот так:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.100:554/video.mp4 -s 640×480 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[мой код трансляции]`

Через ffmpeg не работает. Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: А что не работает? Какие сообщения об ошибках выводятся? Какая версия FFmpeg используется?

Comment: ffmpeg version N-66116-g720c21d В консоли выводит конфигурацию и больше ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь [SoEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684845/using-ffmpeg-to-stream-my-webcams-video-to-youtube), в частности сам вопрос, и ответ на него. У Вас бОльшая ошибка во флагах, к примеру здесь больше флагов:

```
ffmpeg -r 18 -f dshow -s 1280x720 -i video="USB2.0 HD UVC
WebCam":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" 
-vcodec h264 -b:v 1800k -acodec aac -strict experimental -f flv 
"rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/useruser.useruser.codecodecodecode"
```

Так же, стоит взглянуть на [страницу с описаниями флагов и примерами использования стриминга с помощью ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).

В догонку, на GitHub есть [небольшой баш скриптик](https://gist.github.com/olasd/9841772) от olasd(С)

Дополню ответом из ссылки на SoEN:

5. For streaming video from IP camera with rtsp video only output:

   `ffmpeg -re -i input-file  -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://password@(streamaddress with local IP)  -acodec libmp3lame  -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 2048k -vb 400k -maxrate 800k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/(Stream name/key)"`

   Brijesh Verma(С)

Comment: Какую большу ошибку во флагах у ТС вы нашли? Ваш пример для UVC камеры подключенной по USB. У ТС - IP камера, подключенная по сети. Лучше опубликуйте код olasd в качестве ответа - будет более точно (с абстрагированием от bash).

Comment: @MonahTuk, битрейты, буфер, кодеки. Нет многого, из того что нужно YouTube. Именно по этому я указал о том что нужно рассмотреть ранее заданный "похожий" вопрос, поинтересоваться флагами, увидеть пример скрипта. И тогда, написать то, что будет работать. А не дал просто готовый вариант чтоб всё было "ОК"